# Can I test CoreBluetooth iOS application without using third party BLE(Bluetooth Low Energy) device?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, core-bluetooth

I have Mac mini and iOS device having BLE(Bluetooth version 4.0) support.

I am developing an application which works with BLE supported heart rate and foot pod connectors. But right now I am not having any of those connectors.

So will I be able to test my application only using Mac mini and iOS device?
(As there was support of BLE in iOS simulator before iOS7 but now it has been removed.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the LightBlue app from the app store to simulate peripherals, but the heart rate monitor protocol is pretty complex

Comment: Does it simulate speed/cadence like peripheral?

Comment: It just advertises the characteristics.  You need to supply the characteristic values.  You could write an iOS app to advertise a peripheral and supply simulated data

Comment: Thanks, it's working. And good news is that, heart rate monitor protocol is also available in it.